# How to set NSString before calling a method objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

It might be a simple question yet I could not figure out what I am missing.

In ViewControl.h I declared UIColor

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor * myColor;
```

In ViewControl.m I have a method that do something and return new UIColor

```
@synthesize myColor = _myColor;
```

In ViewDidLoad Method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    myColor = [UIColor RedColor];
}

-(void) ShowColorPopUpView
{
    if (!self.wePopoverController)
    {

        ColorViewController *contentViewController = [[ColorViewController alloc] init];
        contentViewController.delegate = self;
        self.wePopoverController = [[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController];
        self.wePopoverController.delegate = self;
        self.wePopoverController.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.navigationController.navigationBar];

        [self.wePopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.tvTweetDetails.frame
                                                  inView:self.view
                                permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp|UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown)
                                                animated:YES];

    } else
    {
        [self.wePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.wePopoverController = nil;
    }
}

-(void) colorPopoverControllerDidSelectColor:(NSString *)hexColor
{
    _myColor = [GzColors colorFromHex:hexColor];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.wePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.wePopoverController = nil;
}
- (UIColor *) returnColor
{
    return _myColor;
}
```

My Question starts here: I have two methods to change a textview font and background color

```
- (IBAction)btnFontColorPopUpMenu:(id)sender
{
    [self ShowColorPopUpView];
    tvTweetDetails.textColor = [self returnColor];
}
- (IBAction)btnTextViewBackGroundColor:(id)sender
{
    [self ShowColorPopUpView];
    tvTweetDetails.backgroundColor = [self returnColor];
}
```

The issue now is when I call the method it return it returns RED and if I call it again it returns the the BlackColor.

How Can I call the method and change the Color to the new one and then return it. I want to get the Black color directly.

I want to execute the method first then return the color but what happens is assign the color before execute the method.

I hope I made it the Question Clear.

Comment: add `myColor = [UIColor RedColor];` in `changeMycolor` method.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Its added already .. sorry I wanted to write myColor instead of myString. @AnoopVaidya

Comment: @bdesham ok this changeMyColor is actually a color picker method that returns a color. So whenever I want to change a TextView background or text color, I call this method. The issue is when I call it it returns the previous color that was chosen before

Comment: It sounds like it depends on what you are doing to pick a new color. If that technique is happening directly in this method (e.g. not via some kind of UI presentation) then you need to assign the new color to your property, not `[UIColor BlackColor]`

Comment: I think you should show how you are changing the color in that method

Comment: changeMyColor method is working perfectly. It changes the color than return it fine. My issue is with changeTextViewBackGround method. What I want to do is call the changeMyColor first to change the color then assign it to the MyTextView background. What happens now it assign the background color before calling the method so it returns red even if i chose something else.  @ctrahey

Comment: No seriously, please show the code for your color picker. It *sounds* like it is happening asynchronously.

Comment: What is your `@synthesize` code for that property?

Regardless, you should change all of the references to `myColor` to `self.myColor`, to access it through the property. I'm not sure how that would cause the behavior you're describing, but it's good practice.

Comment: synthesize myColor = _myColor; and I am using _myColor on my code. @drewmm ..

Comment: Alright. I'd still recommend accessing it with `self.myColor` instead of `_myColor`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'll take a whack at this.

I suspect you are doing some kind of `presentViewController:`... method in your color changer method. That's great, but it has implications. The method you call that in *continues to execute* during that presentation. That means it may return, etc.

This is where the concept of delegates comes in. You may benefit from restructuring the data flows here a bit.

What I suggest (if I am correct about the presentation of a color picker UI) is that you make the following changes:

1. Create a `@protocol ColorPickerDelegate` with one method: `-(void) userChoseColor:(UIColor *) color`
2. Add a `@property (weak) id<ColorPickerDelegate> delegate` to your color picker view controller
3. make your VC here implement that protocol
4. Inside the delegate method, set your local property
5. Implement a custom setter for the local propert, and update the background color *whenever* the color changes.

Comment: First Thank You for the explanation. As I said the color picker is just working fine and it returns the color I choose and assign it to myColor. My problem is changeTextViewBackGround method first assign the myColor to TextView background color then execute the changeMyColor.. I want to do the apposite call changeMyColor first then assign the TextView color @ctrahey

Comment: @iMubarak: I think you need to post more code so we can actually see the control flow you're trying to describe.

Comment: Based on your update: Use your property `self.myColor` to set the new color, then implement a custom setter and change the background color at that time (#5 in my answer)

Comment: I have a custom setter and it assign the new color perfectly. The issue is when I call the btnTextViewBackGroundColor method lets say I choose white color. It assign it to myColor but it doesnt change the TextView color. So when I call it again and choose another color like black it assign it to myColor and change the TextView background to white color. @ctrahey